# Activerecord in Sinatra transactional callbacks warning

Tags: sinatra

Sinatra project with activerecord gem raise a warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Currently, Active Record suppresses errors raised
within `after_rollback`/`after_commit` callbacks and only print them
to the logs. In the next version, these errors will no longer be
suppressed. Instead, the errors will propagate normally just like in
other Active Record callbacks.

You can opt into the new behavior and remove this warning by setting:


**config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true**
```

Gemfile.lock

```
activemodel (4.2.0)

      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
```

How to remove this? thanks!

**EDIT:** The mini project is here https://gist.github.com/williamhqs/c127e5d7018aa61cb02a

Comment: Can you post a minimal Gemfile + sinatra app that exposes the problem? I cannot reproduce it here. This is what I tried: https://gist.github.com/padde/560c81db91b591ae2d84

Comment: hi @PatrickOscity the issue was after call after_commit. Here is the sample project: https://gist.github.com/williamhqs/c127e5d7018aa61cb02a

Comment: @PatrickOscity Just updated gist class Student < ActiveRecord::Base i typed wrong. Thanks!

Comment: and that solved the problem? Sounds strange to me.

Comment: @PatrickOscity oh, no, just in case it didn't work well. If i bundle install activerecord 4.1, there's no this warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you what to do. In Rails, add this line to your application for the time being:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

In Sinatra, you can do it directly on `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

Keep in mind that this configuration option itself will be deprecated with the next release of Active Record.

Comment: add this to the configure block?

Comment: @E.E.33 Rails or Sinatra?

Comment: Sinatra please.

Comment: Then it doesn't really matter, as long as it is done somewhere in the boot process of your app. Putting it in the config block is not necessary, but I guess it's the logical thing to do and should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick is right, to remove the warning and go to the new behaviour, you should add

**Rails :** `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true`

**Sinatra :** `ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true`

I think a little background on what it exactly does is important : 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16537 and https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14488

**Actual Behaviour for after_commit / after_rollback :** When there is an error, the error is logged however it's not shallowed. Meaning that the error does not stop the current execution.

**Futur Behaviour for after_commit / after_rollback :** When there is an error, the error is logged and WILL NOT BE shallowed. Meaning that the error WILL STOP the current execution.

The warning displayed is only here to inform you of that futur behaviour, and this warning will be removed on futur versions of Rails / ActiveRecord.